# how to make a filter for View which find nodes that have a user_reference field referring current user?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I have a content type, named "Task". It has a cck user reference field named "assigned_user".
I want to filter Tasks, which their assigned_user is current user.
how can I use "Token Filter" for this for my view? I installed this module but I didn't find anywhere for inserting tokens in view filter. 
Does exist any better way?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a View of type Nodes
2. Add a filter of `Node: Type = Task` in your view
3. Add another filter from the drop down group `Content`. Now choose `Content: assigned_user`. Now choose the operator `is not empty`
4. Add an argument from the drop down group `Content` named `Content: assigned_user`. Now in the argument settings for `Content: assigned_user` under `action to take if argument is not provided` choose `provide default argument`. Now choose `User ID from logged in user`
5. Add the fields you want in your view e.g. node title etc
6. You're done!

Comment: @Mohsen: did the answer help you?

Comment: do you know how can I add another node type into the following dropdown?? [see here the screenshot](http://s1219.photobucket.com/albums/dd436/partysoft/?action=view&current=abc.jpg)  It drives me nuts, cant't find it anywhere. It had appeared all the node types but now as I changed the node type's name one has dissapeared...